# Create a group ID based on a string column in R

Tags: r

This is probably a dumb question, but how do I create a new group ID based on a string column in R? The values of the ID are arbitrary.

```
ID: the column I want to create

    Name      ID  
   A09john    1     
   J43mary    2     
   B7you      3     
   A09john    1     
   J43mary    2     
   B7you      3
```

I was hoping to use simple codes like below, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you!

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number(as.numeric(????)))
```

Comment: `ID  = as.numeric(factor(Name))` will order them alphabetically. `ID = as.numeric(factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))` or `ID = match(Name, unique(Name))` will order them in the order they first appear.

Comment: @akrun the code ran, but it doesn't create the new column ID...not sure why "Warning in View : Unknown or uninitialised column: `ID`."

Comment: @GregorThomas the error message says it can't find the object "Name": "Error in factor(Name) : object 'Name' not found", but i know that column is there in the data frame.

Comment: @akrun your code doesn't work as row_number() will calculate the row_number in each group.

Comment: yes, you are right.  thanks.  I didn't check the expected output.  Was only correcting the OP's code

Comment: @Susan you are putting that `ID = ` inside `mutate()` right? And you have a column called `"Name"`? And you've loaded `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)`? And you haven't loaded the old `plyr` package?

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, i think it may have to do with the structure of the Name column as it is a string column now, and I need to convert it to a factor?

Comment: `factor` converts it to a `factor`. If you share your sample data with `dput()` then we can be sure we get all the class and structure information correct. Try something like `dput(df1[1:6, ])` for the first 6 rows, and put the result in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidyverse approach that use `dplyr::cur_group_id()` (current group identifier)

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A09john", "J43mary", "B7you", "A09john",  "J43mary", "B7you")
)

new_data <- d |> 
  dplyr::group_by(Name) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::cur_group_id()) |> 
  ungroup()

new_data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   Name       ID
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 A09john     1
#> 2 J43mary     3
#> 3 B7you       2
#> 4 A09john     1
#> 5 J43mary     3
#> 6 B7you       2

# If you want to have the ID based on the order of appearance.
# You have to convert Name to factor first

new_data2 <- d |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) |> 
  dplyr::group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(ID = dplyr::cur_group_id()) |>
  ungroup()

new_data2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   Name [3]
#>   Name       ID
#>   <fct>   <int>
#> 1 A09john     1
#> 2 J43mary     2
#> 3 B7you       3
#> 4 A09john     1
#> 5 J43mary     2
#> 6 B7you       3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`row_number()` is not the solution as it will compute the row number in each group.

Comment: what does "|>" mean here? Thank you!

Comment: I changed the  "|>" to "%>%" in my code, and code ran, but somehow the mutate function won't create the ID column in my data frame. I re-started R and tried still doesn't work. This part of using R is very frustrating for a green hand.

Comment: Hello, |>  is the base pipe! Should work with R  > 4.0.0. Otherwise replacing it with %>% will work for any version of R!

Comment: Publish your precise errors if it still doesn't work!

Comment: Minor correction, `|>` was introduced in R 4.1.0

Comment: workerID is the Name I referred in my Q, but I always remember to use the right column name in my codes ```# A tibble: 1,659 x 372
# Groups:   workerId [553]```when I tried to view it ```> View(data$ID)
Warning in View :
  Unknown or uninitialised column: `ID`.```

Comment: why the groupby? Already the `factor` ing has created the groups, ie `d %>%mutate(group = as.integer(factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))))`

Comment: I have to say: ppl in this forum are so nice! Thank you so much--you make this world a better place.

Comment: I updated my example. Don't forget to save to a new object when adding a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **sequence** and **dplyr** in this way:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(ID = sequence(n()))
```